# UICollectionview and Image loading leading to low memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have a UICollectionView and loading images in each cell. The image loading is handled by SDWebImage and is downloaded as

```
[_ImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon-120"]];
```

The insertion to collection view is handled by code

```
for(NSString *data in datas)
{
    Cell *newCell = [[Cell alloc] initWithDictionary:cellDict];
    [_allcells insertObject:newCell atIndex:0];
    [_collectionView reloadData];                                                        
}
```

The collection view is dismissed when user touches them and I empty the datasource.

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_collectionView setHidden:YES];
    [_allcells removeAllObjects];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setValue:nil forKey:@"memCache"];    
}
```

When I run this code after 5/6 times I get low memory warning. I tried to empty the memcache of image downloads.

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setValue:nil forKey:@"memCache"];
  [_collectionView setHidden:YES];
  [_allcells removeAllObjects];
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  NSLog(@"Received Low Memory");  
}
```

I tried to attach instruments and looked at allocations. Each time image is downloaded I see 5 x 8.1 MB CoreImage allocations. I was under impression that when I call

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setValue:nil forKey:@"memCache"];
```

all allocations should be cleared. Please help me with what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Try to use `[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory]` method for clearing memory cache

Comment: That did not help either. :(

Answer (score 2):

Starting with iOS 7 `NSCache` will automatically remove cache objects only when you set either it's `totalCostLimit` or `countLimit` property.

`SDImageCache` attempts to use `NSCache` `totalCostLimit` to limit the number of mem-cached images. But it never sets the `maxMemoryCost` for the shared `SDImageCache` instance. Apparently you should do it yourself.

That's how they calculate the cost for each image:

```
[self.memCache setObject:image forKey:key cost:image.size.height * image.size.width * image.scale * image.scale];
```

So it's just an image pixel size. We presume that each pixel takes 32 bites in memory (you can check the actual number of bits per pixel using `CGImageGetBitsPerPixel` function, but `SDImageCache` ignores it). So each pixel presumably takes 4 bytes in memory.

Try to set the `maxMemoryCost` limit to a reasonable amount. Something like this:

```
NSProcessInfo *info = [NSProcessInfo processInfo];
// Compute total cost limit in bytes
NSUInteger totalCostLimit = (NSUInteger)(info.physicalMemory * 0.15); // Use 15% of available RAM

// Divide totalCostLimit in bytes by number of bytes per pixel
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache].maxMemoryCost = totalCostLimit / 4;
```

If you don't set the `maxMemoryCost` of `SDImageCache` it will only remove mem-cached images on memory warnings.

You can read more about image caching and `NSCache` [here](http://outscope.net/blog/image-caching)